# How do I convert a text file received via a web call to a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am attempting to convert this [text](http://media.steampowered.com/apps/440/scripts/items/items_game.50549368e72271598046a4227c757ee9e9b6e9cd.txt) file to a python dictionary.

The basic format is

```
"items_game"
{
    "game_info"
    {
        "first_valid_class"         "1"
        "last_valid_class"          "9"
        "first_valid_item_slot"     "0"
        "last_valid_item_slot"      "10"
        "num_item_presets"          "4"
    }
    "qualities"
    {
        "key"           "value"
    }
    ...
    "community_market_item_remaps"
    {
        "Supply Crate"
        {
            "Supply Crate 2"            "1"
            "Supply Crate 3"            "1"
        }
        "Decoder Ring"
        {
            "Winter Key"                "1"
            "Summer Key"                "1"
            "Naughty Winter Key 2011"   "1"
            "Nice Winter Key 2011"      "1"
            "Scorched Key"              "1"
            "Fall Key 2012"             "1"
            "Eerie Key"                 "1"
            "Naughty Winter Key 2012"   "1"
            "Nice Winter Key 2012"      "1"
        }
    }
}
```

This file is almost a dictionary, but not quite. Is there a way to convert this into a dictionary so that I can access each level of the dictionary by the keys? I'd like to do something like:

```
foreach key in dictName['items_game']['community_market_item_remaps']['Decoder Ring']:
    # do something
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is ugly, but it seems to work, assuming the linked file is `test.txt`:

```
import re

a = open('test.txt').read()

a = a.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', ' ')
a = a.replace('{', ':{').replace('}', '},\n')

b =  re.sub('(\".*?\") *(\".*?\")', r'\1:\2,', a)

b = "{%s}" % b

dictName = eval(b)
for key in dictName['items_game']['community_market_item_remaps']['Decoder Ring']:
    print key
```

The output is:

```
Fall Key 2012
Eerie Key
Nice Winter Key 2011
Nice Winter Key 2012
Summer Key
Scorched Key
Winter Key
Naughty Winter Key 2011
Naughty Winter Key 2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting data to json and then reading the json into variable.

[test.txt](http://media.steampowered.com/apps/440/scripts/items/items_game.50549368e72271598046a4227c757ee9e9b6e9cd.txt)

```
import re
import json
a = open('test.txt').read()
a = re.sub('"[ \t]*"', '":"', a)
a = re.sub('"\s+"', '","', a)
a = re.sub('"\s+{', '":{', a)
a = re.sub('}\s+"', '},"', a)
a = '{%s}' % a
b = json.loads(a)
```

Comment: Using json.loads() avoids running eval() on data from an external source.  I like this approach.