# How to parse a txt file from steam

Tags: php, xml, steam

How can I parse this txt [file](http://media.steampowered.com/apps/570/scripts/items/items_game.f02cc9618b2cf21b0454dc02a8cf73ba5e8a66aa.txt) or how could i turn it into xml(if it's possible)?
Help please.

Edit: Yes, that is not a json.

Comment: Look at the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544840/php-json-or-array-to-xml

Comment: I don't think it's a JSON, it's look like but is not. You need to write your own parser.

Comment: @Kakawait: it's definitely NOT json. there's no `:` between the key/value pairs.

Comment: you need to write a parser. check PHP_ParserGenerator and PHP_Lexer on PEAR

Comment: My bad, I took a brief glance and didn't notice the dissimilarities. Hope you get it sorted out.

Comment: There was a similar question related to python here that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182398/how-do-i-convert-a-text-file-received-via-a-web-call-to-a-dictionary